# DBeaver окно авто-дополнения не закрывается

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbeaver

Столкнулся со странной проблемой.

Окно авто-дополнения не закрывается автоматически и перекрывает окно с кодом.

Например, я вручную набираю "select * from table_name as t", но подсказка "select" так и остается развернутой, хотя должна исчезнуть за ненадобностью.

При такой раскладе приходиться либо производить ввод кода с использованием подсказки, либо убирать их вручную мышкой.

P. S. Стоит последняя версия DBeaver CE из Microsoft Store.

[image: Активное окно с ненужной подсказкой]